# wpf - how should I auto-grey-out a textbox when it's associated radiobutton is not selected?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What's the best approach to auto-grey-out a textbox if it's associated radiobutton is not selected?

I've got an [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681773/wpf-whats-wrong-with-this-code-trying-to-get-isenabled-to-bind-to-dependency) out re using a dependency property (which I haven't got working) for this, however I'm not sure this is the appropriate approach.  So basically when RadioButton 1 is selected the text field is enabled, however when RadioButton 2 is selected then the textfield should got NOT enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" />
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioButton2}" />
```