# Combo Box is not disabled when radio button is selected

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, radio-button

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681835/wpf-how-should-i-auto-grey-out-a-textbox-when-its-associated-radiobutton-is-n) in an example and it seemed to work fine.  Then I applied it to the main project we are working on, and it failed.  Here's the relevant snips of code:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}" SelectedItem="{Binding TableName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" Width="180" 
SelectionChanged="Combo_SelectionChanged" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rdBtnList}" Margin="6,20,6,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

and the radio button that controls it:

```
<RadioButton Content="By List" Height="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ListSelect, Mode=TwoWay}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,24,0"  Name="rdBtnList" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Background="DodgerBlue" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

Does anyone see anything (regarding the IsEnabled situation) that seems incorrect?

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: @Josh No. No errors.  This is frustrating

Comment: You want `ComboBox` to be disabled in case `RadioButton` is checked or unchecked? As per code it will get enable in case radioButton is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the way the code is written, the combobox is ENABLED when the radio button is selected.  If you want the opposite to happen, when the radio button is selected the combo box should be disabled, you need a converter to make the boolean value the opposite.

```
public class OppositeBoolConverter : IValueConverter {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            return !System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, add a namespace reference and add the converter to the binding for the combobox:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE"

<local:OppositeBoolConverter x:Key="cnt" />

IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource cnt}, ElementName=rdBtnList}"
```

Comment: What I'm still not understanding is (aside from enable/disable) why it changes using my example, but does not change in the project.  Enabled or Disabled is not the question I'm asking.  Its more about changing between the two.